# How can I access the up method parameter' value in current method

Tags: java, multithreading, stack

When I debug a program, I can click the up method in call stack, and check the up method parameter' value.
How can I do this in code

```
public class Example() {

  public void method1(String s) {
    method2();
  }

  public void method2(/*whitout any parameters*/){

    //how can I access the parameter value of 's' in method1's paramters at here
  }

}
```

Comment: I also want to know

Comment: You can't because  s is not visible within method2.

Comment: You could theroretically by using some sort of ugly reflection code. But even if that were possible it is not reasonable to do so. Please elaborate on what you want to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya it is very difficult to elaborate this, but it is very useful, if it's possible, I can resolve some problems.

Comment: Now, `method2()` may be called from many places, not only from `method1()`, so it could well be that there is no `method1()` and hence no `s` to access. So it seems to me your question does not make a lot of sense when we think about it.

Comment: Alternatives include: (1) Make `s` a field in the class rather than a parameter to `method1()` (2) add `s` as a parameter to `method2()` too.

Comment: Inline with @OleV.V. 's point, this would violate the encapsulation of a method, which is a core concept of Object Oriented Programming.  This would be highly inadvisable even if it is possible.